# Find MAX value of column automatically in SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently working with a spreadsheet where I have column with ID's. And I want to find MAX value +1 in this column whenever someone add a new row and place it in correct cell. Any ideas how that could be done automatically? The only user interaction should be adding new row. Let me show you a screenshot to clarify what is my question.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can try some code and see if it works, what you need to write is `onEdit` function behind your spreadsheet. Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) and [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an onChange installable trigger and set it to this function as shown below.

```
function onAddRow(e) 
{
  if(e.changeType=='INSERT_ROW')
  {
    //Logger.log('here');
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rg=sh.getDataRange();
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    var max='-1';
    for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
    {
      if(vA[i][12]>max)
      {
        max=vA[i][12];
      }
    }
    var arg=sh.getActiveRange();
    var row=arg.getRow();
    //Logger.log(row);
    sh.getRange(row,13).setValue(max + 1);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it through this setup (in my case id was "A" column):

```
function myFunction() {

  var column = 0;
  var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Задачи");
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, 1);

  var max = 0;

  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {  
    var id = vals[row][column];
    if (id > max) {
        max = id;
    }
  }
  for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {  
    var id = vals[row][column];
    if (id.length === 0) {
      max = max+1;
      worksheet.getRange(row+1, column+1).setValue(max);        
    }
  }  
}
```